# Where is en_US.UTF-8 defined?

Tags: unicode, locale, standards

Where is the actual definition of the collating and comparison mappings for en_US.UTF-8?  I assume there's some standards document, reference source code, and/or data table available somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Unicode.

`/usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_COLLATE` is created by `localedef`. `man localedef` shows the input path `/usr/share/i18n/locales`.

`/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US` § `LC_COLLATE` references file `iso14651_t1`, which references `iso14651_t1_common`, which is a [file published by ISO](https://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/14651/ed-4/), which tells us the originating source `unidata-9.0.0.txt`. Run `git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git` to see the history of these files.

http://enwp.org/ISO_14651 says the ISO standard and UCA are aligned, so the corresponding file at unicode.org is [allkeys.txt](https://unicode.org/Public/UCA/).

Comment: Maybe also mention the [Common Locale Data Repository.](https://cldr.unicode.org/)

Comment: Why, though? That does not bring us forward. CLDR is just a repackaging of the original Unicode files. See directory `common/uca` in `cldr-common-*.zip`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had already found the CLDR, but that's a bit of a rathole.  The files in /usr/share/i18n make this all quite a bit more obvious.  BTW, the link above doesn't work; http://cldr.unicode.org/ works, but not the https flavor.